# Create custom DOM event with custom data

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom, browser

I have this code:

```
   let event = new Event('sumanload', {
      value: 'foo'
    });

    window.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Here is the error:

[image]

What I want to do is pass custom data as the event data. Is there a way to do this? Right now, TypeScript will complain if you include an unknown property.

Comment: what if you pass it to the instance? like `event.value = 'foo'`?

Comment: that might work, I will try it

Comment: it's a similar problem - I can't define a custom field on event itself, because the custom field/property does not exist...there must be some correct way to do this

Comment: Then I don't know. I see someone else encountered a similar issue on [`redux`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46016711/redux-form-typescript-pass-custom-props)

Comment: Can you try a new [CustomEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent) object? They support a  `detail` property of the initialization object with any data type. As per the link, some browsers need a polyfill (go on, guess which one).

Comment: ah yes that might work, let me try it, if you think it's the right answer, add an answer I will upvote

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a [`CustomEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent#Specifications) instead of an `Event` object. Custom event objects specifically allow you to add a `detail` property to the initialiser object passed as the second parameter during constructions.

```
let event = new CustomEvent('sumanload', {
    detail: 'foo'
});

window.dispatchEvent(event);
```

where `detail` can be of any data type including object.

I have successfully attached custom properties directly to a CustomEvent object in the past ( as in `event.value = 'foo'`) but I don't know if TypeScript will let you do that.

Check the MDN link above for a polyfill if you need to support older browsers like IE.